# what does "make it" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I was doing my English homework and I didn´t get an excersice.

Circle the correct explanation for each sentence

> "The road is under the avalanche, you might not make it to the airport"
>
> a. Lucy and Luis might not get to the airport
>
> b. the road might not get to the airport

Which of them are the correct answer?

I really don´t understand, please I really need your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, *make it to* means "arrive at a certain place", and there is often an implied time constraint.

For example, my son might say:

> I missed the bus. Now I won't make it to school.

This could mean that there's no way he can get to school, or it could mean there is no way he can get to school without being late.

In your example, we can assume that cars can't drive to the airport now, because the avalanche has covered the road and made it impassible. The road still goes to the airport, so answer (b) is incorrect. However, the people traveling to the airport may not be able to get to the airport – not until the road is cleared off and reopened. If Lucy and Luis have tickets for a flight that leaves in two hours, and the road won't be reopened for several hours, there's a good chance they won't make it to the airport, and there's a good chance they won't make their flight, either.

Answer (score 0):

"Make it" means

> successfully achieve something

In this phrase means:

> Be able to arrive in the airport.

Answer (score -3):

**make it** means a lot of things, you can check every meaning in this [link](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/make+it)

In this case, **make it** means the article could not be able to start and the airport could be not available.

> "The road is under the avalanche, the airport could be not available."

Comment: It is not about availability of airport, it is about road. since it says "The road is under the avalanche".